# LINQ - How to translate patindex and substring

Tags: linq, t-sql

Could someone help me translate this Transact-SQL statement to LINQ?

```
select distinct SUBSTRING ( car# ,1 , PATINDEX ( '%[0123456789]%' , car# )-1 ) from dbo.Purchases
```

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look : **http://forums.asp.net/t/1599147.aspx/1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework and .NET 4.0, take a look at the [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.aspx) class. It contains definitions for common built-in SQL functions (like [`PatIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx)) that can be used in your LINQ to Entities queries. When used in your queries, these functions are translated into the corresponding SQL function.